# How to insert HTML code in a component Angular 8

Tags: html, typescript, angular8

I need to insert HTML5 code inside my component.ts, I'm trying to reflect that code in my component.html, how can I insert it including the CSS and the Angular's directives? I have to do it like that because the web site needs to change depending on the current hour.
I'm using angular 8. Thanks

I've used in the component.html the function [innerHtml]="htmlToAdd" inside a div label, and in the component.ts have created a var type any called "htmlToAdd" in which one I put all the HTML code, it worked but it doesn't detect the Angular's directives, and just a few styles of the CSS. I have CSS styles in the own component folder and in the folder styles.css, but the browser only detects some of the styles in the styles.css folder. The trigger doesn't work neither.

```
htmlToAdd : any;
this.htmlToAdd = '<p><button class="btn-sec app-btn-years" (click)="toggleDetails2019()" (click)="toggle2019()"><div *ngIf="text2019;then yearClose else yearDetails"></div><div [@showMonths]="status2019"></div>'+
             '</button></p>';
```

I expect each time the browser is refreshed the web site show the code inserted in the component.ts with the CSS, the trigger and the angular's directives working, not only the html structure as it does right now.